# Inflating multiple layouts in list view ?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

Have a fragment with a listView that should be inflated as follows :
one with a different layout (custom row),position two with (slider) and from position 3 (item_layout) have gone through quite a lot of resources on the web and stack overflow which didn't solve my purpose looking for a sample or tutorial of this kind.

Comment: Create a custom Adapter and based on index inflate the view in `getView()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use [`header`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) instead of different types of items, because you will not recycle first two rows.

> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before
>   setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter).

Example:

```
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_first_two_rows, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    listView.setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapter(...));
```

Comment: you are a genius :) this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM0 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 2; 


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(getItem(position) instanceof Type1List){
        type = TYPE_ITEM0;
    }
    else if(getItem(position) instanceof BingImageBean){
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;
    }
    else if(getItem(position) instanceof InuvoSearchType3Bean){
        type = TYPE_ITEM2;
    }

    return type;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    if(viewType == 0){

        // InuvoSearch Type 1

        InuvoSearchType_1_ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null || (Integer)convertView.getTag(R.id.view_type) != 0){

            holder = new InuvoSearchType_1_ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inuvosearch_list_type1,parent,false);

            holder.txtInuvoTitle        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInuvoTitle);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.view_type, 0);
        }
        else {              
            holder = (InuvoSearchType_1_ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();               
        }


        return convertView;

    }
    else if(viewType == 1)
    {

        // Bing Related Images

        ImageViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null || (Integer)convertView.getTag(R.id.view_type) != 1){
            holder = new ImageViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagesearch_list,parent,false);                

            holder.imageView1   = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.view_type, 1);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ImageViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;

    }
    else if(viewType ==2)
    {

        // InuvoSearch Type 3

        InuvoSearchType_3_ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null || (Integer)convertView.getTag(R.id.view_type) != 2){

            holder = new InuvoSearchType_3_ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inuvosearch_list_type3,parent,false);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.view_type, 2);

        }
        else{
            holder = (InuvoSearchType_3_ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.baseLayout.setId(position);

        return convertView;

    }
    return null;

}
```

static class ImageViewHolder{

```
    //Bing Related Images Holder:

    private ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3;
    private ProgressBar progressBariamgeView1,progressBariamgeView2,progressBariamgeView3;
    private RelativeLayout baseLayout;

}

 static class InuvoSearchType_1_ViewHolder{

    //InuvoSearchType_1_ViewHolder:
    private TextView txtInuvoTitle,txtInuvoDescription,txtInuvoLink;
    private ImageView icon;
    private RelativeLayout baseLayout;

 }

static class InuvoSearchType_3_ViewHolder{

    //InuvoSearchType_3_ViewHolder:     
    private TextView txtInuvoTitle,txtInuvoDescription,txtInuvoLink;
    private ImageView icon;     
    private RelativeLayout baseLayout;
}


   Like I shown in the above code, we can create different layout for listview using getItemViewType in getView method. Based on the type value, set the xml  layout. The above code must be used in Adapterclass of the listview
```